# Haskell: Array Loop Comparison Equivalent

Tags: haskell

I am trying to compare certain aspects of two linked lists.

The arrays both have format (assume a...p derive Eq):

```
linkedList1 = [(a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)]
linkedList2 = [(a, f, k, l), (a, b, g, m)]
```

What I hope to accomplish here is as follows:

- I want to input an index, to be referenced in each quadruple.
- For that index, I want to find out, for each quadruple in linkedList 1, how many times the value at that index is identical to the value at the same index in each of the quadruples in linkedList 2.

For example on the above linked lists, inputting the two linkedlists and the index 1 would return a value of 2 as the second value in the first quadruple of linkedList1 = the second value in the second quadruple of linkedList2.

Inputting the two linkedlists and the index 3, however, will return 0 as none of the 4th letters in the quadruples of the 1st linked list match any of the 4th letters in the suadruples of the 2nd linked list.

Any suggestions how to achieve this/get started? I've been trying to implement a recursive map function but it's been pretty choppy progress.

Comment: As given, `myArray1` and `myArray2` are neither arrays nor two-dimensional; they're linked lists of quadruples. That doesn't seem to correspond to the pseudo code. Could you provide some actual examples of input values, and what you'd expect the result to be?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited it to answer your questions & correct the types.

Comment: In the top, do you mean to count `a==e | a==e | a==m` , and `b== f | b==j | b==n` ? Because as stated, it doesn't seem to fit with the pseudocode.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but up to the pseudocode it seems that you want to count the number of times any element in linkedList1 is equal to any element in linkedList2 regardless of the index. Could you provide an actual example?

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I understand that you're asking for help with implementing a function, so we don't expect you to supply the code for such a function (although an attempt would be nice). Some code that represents sample input values, and what the expected output values should be, would be a start. That code ought to compile.

Comment: The code and specifications seem to contradict each other. Based on your code, you want to count the number of tuple elements that are the same, so where for every tuple `t1` in `l1`, and every tuple `t2` in `l2`, `t1[i] == t2[i]`.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, clearly the sudocode didn't help clarify, so I've removed it entirely and tried to explain myself as well as possible using examples.

Comment: I think what is causing confusion is ``[(a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)]`` list of quadruples. Whereas you say "list in list", which should be ``[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]]``

Comment: Apologies i meant list of quadruples, I'll edit now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
howManyEqualAtIndex l1 l2 0
=> 2
howManyEqualAtIndex l1 l2 1
=> 2
howManyEqualAtIndex l1 l2 2
=> 1
howManyEqualAtIndex l1 l2 3
=> 0
```

---

```
l1 = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]
l2 = [('a', 'f', 'k', 'l'), ('a', 'b', 'g', 'm')]

--List comprehension checking all combinations.
--Predicate that they are equal
howManyEqualAtIndex xs ys idx = length [() | x<-xs, y<-ys, equalAt x y idx]

--Hardcoded for quads, can be extended to other n-tuples,
--or changed to list version commented out below
equalAt (a,_,_,_) (b,_,_,_) 0 = a == b
equalAt (_,a,_,_) (_,b,_,_) 1 = a == b
equalAt (_,_,a,_) (_,_,b,_) 2 = a == b
equalAt (_,_,_,a) (_,_,_,b) 3 = a == b

--equalAt :: (Eq a) =>  [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Bool
--equalAt xs ys idx = xs !! idx == ys !! idx
```

Comment: In `length [equalAt x y idx | x<-xs, y<-ys, equalAt x y idx]` The first `equalAt x y idx` is immaterial, and could be replaced by anything else, e.g. `()`. Otherwise, another alternative is `length . filter id $ [equalAt x y idx | x<-xs, y<-ys]`, but your code is probably simpler.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, started without the predicate, so needed to check the bool there, just as your other suggestion.